# Reusable pictures of Dudhu Chak (city in Pakistan)

Tags: data-request, images

I am looking for pictures of [Dudhu Chak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dudhu_Chak) to illustrate [this Wikivoyage article](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Dudhu_Chak).

Requirements:

- Free
- [Reusable on Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Licensing#Acceptable_licenses)

  - Modifications OK
  - Commercial use OK
  - Redistribution under same license OK
  - Perpetual

Are there such pictures?

- Google Images does not show anything when filtering for reusable images
- Wikimedia Commons has nothing either

Comment: I am from Dudhu Chak. I can provide you as many pictures as you want. E Mail me at m_adnan_k@yahoo.com